# Getting "unknown function" for inhouse developed user defined function

Tags: neo4j, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to test user defined functions in neo4j 3.1. So I wrote this:

```
public class Udf
{
    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Context
    public Log log;

    @UserFunction("test.id")
    public Long id(@Name("node") Node node)
    {
        return node.getId();
    }
}
```

and a test function like this:

```
public class UdfTest
{
    @Rule
    public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()
        .withProcedure(Udf.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToExtractIdProperty() throws Throwable
    {
        try (Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4j.boltURI() , Config.build().withEncryptionLevel(Config.EncryptionLevel.NONE).toConfig()))
        {
            Session session = driver.session();

            long nodeId = session.run("CREATE (p) RETURN test.id(p)")
                    .single()
                    .get(0).asLong();

            assertEquals(nodeId, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run the test it prompts:

```
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unknown function 'test.id' (line 1, column 19 (offset: 18))
"CREATE (p) RETURN test.id(p)"
                   ^
```

When I change the `@UserFunction` to `@Procedure` and a bunch of other changes, I can call the exact same method using `CALL .. YIELD` clause.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `withProdcedure` method instead of the `withFunction` method on `Neo4jRule` in your test. Change that line to:

```
@Rule
public Neo4jRule neo4j = new Neo4jRule()
    .withFunction(Udf.class);
```